# How can I attach a generated vcard to a mail message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, vpim

Current code that isn't working
    attachments["contact.vcf"] = {:content=> card.to_s} 
    mail(:to =>card.email, :subject =>"Test")

Example Code I've been using:
http://firstruby.wordpress.com/2007/12/10/vcard-exporting-through-rubyonrails/

Comment: Figured it out. Need to encode the attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Needed to encode the attachment.

Comment: can you be more specific please :)